# cv::drawMatches(...) not drawing

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I've been trying to make a SURF implementation work and I have been having some trouble, now I finally think i got it 'right' but I have one small problem. 
The problem is pretty straight forward and I am sure its something simple but I can't solve it. The image displays right and everything but the matches are not drawn. Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"



using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv ){

if ( argc != 3 ) {
    printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image1_Path> <Image2_Path>\n");
    return -1;
}

Mat image, image2;
image = imread( argv[1], 0 );
image2 = imread(argv[2], 0);

if ( !image.data ){
    printf("No image data \n");
    return -1;
}

if ( !image2.data ){
    printf("No image data \n");
    return -1;  
}

/*
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FastFeatureDetector::create(15);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
detector->detect(image, keypoints1);
detector->detect(image2, keypoints2);



Ptr<xfeatures2d::SURF> extractor = xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;

extractor->compute(image, keypoints1, descriptors1);
extractor->compute(image2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

BFMatcher::BFMatcher matcher(L2<float>);
//BruteForceMatcher<L2<float> > matcher;
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);
*/

Ptr<xfeatures2d::SURF> surf = cv::xfeatures2d::SURF::create();
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
surf->detectAndCompute(image,noArray(), keypoints1, descriptors1, true);
//BFMatcher::BFMatcher matcher(L2<float>);
BFMatcher::BFMatcher matcher(NORM_HAMMING);
vector<DMatch> matches;
Mat res;

matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2, matches);
drawMatches(image, keypoints1, image2, keypoints2, matches, res);



namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow("Display Image", res);

waitKey(0);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: your `descriptors2` is empty -> no matches -> no draw. You need to add `surf->detectAndCompute(image2,noArray(), keypoints2, descriptors2, true);`

Comment: yeaaaah just found that haha thank you!! ill try it right away.

Comment: @Miki Thanks! Still no draw tho, my keypoints stil return at 0. Any idea why?

Comment: try setting the last parameter to `false` in both calls to `detectAndCompute`

Comment: Nice!! Now I think I've got too many. I get this error: `Keypoints1 size: 6737 Keypoints2 size: 7200
Descriptor1 size: [64 x 6737] Descriptor2 size: [64 x 7200]`
`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((type == CV_8U && dtype == CV_32S) || dtype == CV_32F) in batchDistance, file /Users/Darwin/opencvcontrib/opencv/modules/core/src/stat.cpp, line 3792
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/Darwin/opencvcontrib/opencv/modules/core/src/stat.cpp:3792: error: (-215) (type == CV_8U && dtype == CV_32S) || dtype == CV_32F in function btchDistance
Abort trap: 6`

Comment: You cannot use `NORM_HAMMING` in the matcher. Use NORM_L2 (default): `BFMatcher::BFMatcher matcher;`

Comment: @Miki thanks man. I was trying to use that but was doing it opencv2 style.

Comment: However I do have too many points. I guess mask is exactly for that but im not shure how to specify it.

Comment: @Miki Got it!!!! Thank you very much for your help.